# Related Rates using circles

Tags: calculus

can someone please help? I'm taking Calculus, but I'm really having trouble understanding the concept of related rates.

A jogger runs around a circular track of radius 55 ft. Let (*x*,*y*) be her coordinates, where the origin is the center of the track. When the jogger's coordinates are (33, 44), her *x*-coordinate is changing at a rate of 17 ft/s. Find dy/*dt*.

I tried making a triangle within the circle, and differentiating the Pythagorean Theorem to find the hypotenuse's length, but I'm stuck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did the right thing. It differentiates to:

$$2x\frac{dx}{dt} + 2y\frac{dy}{dt} =0$$

You know x, y, and $\frac{dx}{dt}$. Simply solve for $\frac{dy}{dt}$

Answer (score 2):

The equation of the circle the jogger is running about is simply $$x^2+y^2=55^2. $$ Differentiating yields $$2xdx+2ydy=0. $$ Multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{dt}$ yields $$2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}=0. $$ The problem stated that at the point $(33,44)$, $\frac{dx}{dt}=17.$ Plugging these values into the equation directly above, we obtain $$2(33)(17)+(2)(44)\frac{dy}{dt}=0. $$ You are solving for $\frac{dy}{dt}.$ We see $$\boxed{\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{51}{4}.} $$

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a related rates problem relying on implicit differentiation.  Find the equation of a circle, then take a differential and divide by dt (also known as taking the derivative with respect to time).  Then you substitute in dx/dt with the value you are given, and solve for dy/dt.